# finding elements that are under or above div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I have a pretty strange question here. How do you find out if there are any other div elements under or above a specific div element. For my project that I'm working on right now, I have a bunch of smaller divs underneeth and i want a selector that allows the users to select any number of those divs. The way I thought of was to use a resizeable div that can be dragged around as the selector div on z-index of n+1 and the rest of the divs that are to be selected is on z-index of n. To do this I will use a combination of:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

and

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

which lets me make a draggable and resizeable object div that I can use to select the divs underneath. Is there some elegant way of doing this or do I just have to go and do this the hard way by finding out it's location and manually find all the divs that are under it.

Also if there's another way to do this more elegantly i'd be all ears.

Thanks

Comment: what about `.next()`?

Comment: by above and under do you mean the physical location or parent/child relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI, use the UI's [Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid).

From the source of the example in the link:

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ol>

<script>
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = jQuery(ld).parent();
var child = jQuery(id).children();
```

I hope that it will be a correct solution.

Comment: Add an extra space before each "Var" for it to show as code, and rename "Var" to "var" as "Var" is nothing in javascript, but "var" sets a variable declaration.

Comment: i think this gets child elements rather than elements that are physically beneath or intersecting the div

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to find divs that are physically underneeth a div for example 

<div>
 a bunch of other divs
</div>
<div id="selector"></div> 

the goal is to find out the other divs that intersects selector div